# Tint image with two different colors

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I have an image with two colors: circle filled with red in center and white ring around it.

[image]

Is there any way of coloring that image with two different colors? For example: fill inner circle with green and outer with blue.

Is it possible to change color only for outer circle?

Tinting image like:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "circles")?.tintWithColor(UIColor.red)
```

always changes color of two circles.

Comment: Can you show image that you'r describing in ques.

Comment: You can not made change on Image so use UIView.

Comment: why is this downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not made change on Image like this so use UIView.

Use this Custom Class

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CircleView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var strokeWidth: CGFloat = 0
    @IBInspectable var outerFillColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear
    @IBInspectable var innerFillColor: UIColor = UIColor.red
    @IBInspectable var strokeColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear
    @IBInspectable var innerWidth: CGFloat = 0

    @IBInspectable var bgColor: UIColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = bgColor
        }
    }


    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.backgroundColor = bgColor
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

        shapeLayer.fillColor = outerFillColor.cgColor

        shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor

        shapeLayer.lineWidth = strokeWidth

        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        let iFrame = CGRect(x: self.frame.width/2 - innerWidth/2,
                            y: self.frame.height/2 - innerWidth/2,
                            width: innerWidth, height: innerWidth)

        let innerCirclePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: iFrame)

        let shapeLayerInner = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayerInner.path = innerCirclePath.cgPath
        shapeLayerInner.fillColor = innerFillColor.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayerInner)
    }


}
```

**How to Use**

1. Take a UIView from storyboard and Assign the class.

[image]

2. Now use the property

   - **StrokeWidth:** Outer Circle width.
   - **StrokeColor:** Outer circle color.
   - **outerFillColor:** Outer circle fill color.
   - **innerWidth :** Inner circle width.
   - **innerFillColor:** Inner circle fill color.
   - **bgcolor:** background color of uiview, it is already available in the storyboard. It is additional.

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Now change change color from storyboard and check. Properties are immediately  applied on the storyboard so you dont need to run the project.